# Filtering using JQuery to omit children of parents

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the class 'active' from all elements of class 'popup' where the elements are not in the parent tree of a specific element. I thought it would be something like:-

```
$(".active.popup").not($("#element").parents()).removeClass("active");
```

But I sense the use of `parents()` here is not valid?

Example Html:-

```
<div>
    <div class="popup active">
        <!-- leave this active class - it is in parent tree of #element -->
        <div>
            <div class="popup active">
                <!-- leave this active class - it is in parent tree of #element -->
                <a id="#element"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="popup active">
        <!-- remove this active class - not in parent tree of #element -->
        <div>
            <div class="popup active">
                <!-- remove this active class - not in parent tree of #element -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<div>
    <div class="popup active">
        <!-- remove this active class - not in parent tree of #element -->
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML

Comment: It would really help to see the accompanying HTML, along with a description of the elements you do/do not want to select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  window.disableOnActive = function() {
    var element = document.getElementById("element");
    $(".active.popup").each(function(i, v) {
      if ($(element.parentElement).has(v).length == 0) {
        $(v).removeClass("active");
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test">
  <div>
    <div id="element">
      <p class="active popup">
        I am active but not in parent
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <p class="active popup">
    I am active outside the parent 1
  </p>
  <p class="active popup">
    I am active outside the parent 1
  </p>
</div>
<button onClick="disableOnActive()">Disable Active
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, that has taken me forward.

Comment: It is time to start learn to _indent_ the code properly...and that alone can get you downvotes

Comment: @LGSon Ok, Next time  I will take care this.